# Call servlet from a method Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

Tags: jsp, servlets

In my project I have to use Runtime.getRuntime().exec() method in servlet and from this method I have to call a servlet. But when I wrote codes it doesnot work.
I wrote :

```
Process process = null;

process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/servletName");
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception? Paste the logs here

Comment: What you are trying to do seems meaningless to me.  servlets run in a web container. Runtime.getRuntime().exec executes OS binaries.

Comment: Runtime execute an OS process, what you can try do is run a process that open a browser with the url to the servlet, not sure if this would work... just give you some idea :)

Comment: Is there an executable tha could be run with `/servletName`? If you want to call a servlet or something else it is best to create a local java program that will either call a servlet programmatically via http request or start a browser with the desired url. Or simply call from the `exec` a browser with the url. Something along these lines.